# Is there a simple way of finding the font used in a piece of copied text?

Tags: macos, font

I'm trying to copy a small amount of text from a pdf to a Pages doc. On pasting, the font isn't the same. Is there a way of finding the font used in the copied text so I can set it after pasting?

Comment: What app provided the copy text you clipped? Preview or something else? What version of that app or macOS would be two good edits to add to the question if no one jumps in with a generic answer.

Comment: Thanks, bmike, I don't know which app the pdf was generated from.

Comment: But you have to know what app did the copy? QuickLook preview? Preview app? Can you give us anything to help us help you?

Comment: Thx again, I copied from the document using cmd-C from a Preview document.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't tell us which program you are copying from it will be difficult to give you a definitive answer, however...

In my tests with a PDF of my own creation preview.app does not seem to show font info in the info panel. However (the free) Adobe reader will show what fonts are used in the document if you go to File > Properties and select the Fonts tab.

That will show you what fonts are used in the document but not what font is at a specific point in the document.

There are web sites which purport to tell you what font is used from a picture (or screen shot) of the font in question. I remember trying this out a year or so ago with mixed results, but it might be worth searching for online.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your effort and answer. I was hoping the font information would be in the metadata that accompanies the copy that some app could read.

Comment: We shall see @JonHall - more answers can arise and someone might edit this when they see its missing an option.